# How to keep track of which side the pointer is on

Tags: c, pointers

I often find it challenging to think through where to put the pointer. I know I need a pointer, but not sure whether it is to go on the left or right. To take a simple example:

```
typedef struct Animal {
    char*           name;
    unsigned int    age;
    unsigned int    weight;
    void            (*print_func) (struct Animal *);

} Animal;
```

`char*` is easy for me to see, remember, but the function pointer at the bottom is more difficult. What would be an explanation of when a `*` goes before and after? Is this a common confusion for beginners learning C?

Comment: I'm sure there's duplicates here, but to summarize: C is a very much free-form language where spaces doesn't matter. So `char*foo;`, `char *foo;`, `char* foo;`, and `char * foo;` all mean the same thing.

Comment: When declaring a variable, function or a parameter as a pointer, the `*` *always* goes before the name of the variable, function or parameter. Except when that name is omitted (for a parameter), when it goes before the name that is omitted. ‎

Comment: As for `void (*print_func) (struct Animal *);` that declares `print_func` as a pointer to a function (with no return value) , while `void *(print_func) (struct Animal *);` declares a function which returns `void *`. [The spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) might help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `char* c`, the compiler interprets `c` as the name of a variable. In this case, `char *` is type of the variable: a pointer to a char. So far so good.  The C pre-processor does not cares about spaces here and you can even write like either that or `char *c`, or even `char*c`. It is a pointer to a char. A pointer is a variable which contains a memory location.

Now when you write

```
    void            (*print_func) (struct Animal *);
```

you are not saying the `*print_func` is a pointer to void; rather, you saying that `*print_func` is a pointer to a function. The compiler knows that because of the parenthesis following the symbol name. Now the pre-processor understands that you have a pointer to a function. I will interpret that `void` as meaning that this function returns void.

Comment: so in C does `(*print_func)` always mean function pointer? Or only in the context of a struct, or how can you tell that it's a function pointer?

Comment: @David542, no `(*print_func)` is not always a function. In the example it is a pointer to a function because it is preceded by a return type (`void`) and followed by an argument list (`(struct Animal *)`). Alas, C syntax is not always obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**The question is**: does the asterisk follow the type-identifier or precede the variable-identifier?

**My personal preference**: before the variable-identifier.

**Example:**

```
struct Animal on_stack, *to_allocate;
```

Otherwise you had to write:

```
struct Animal  on_stack;
struct Animal* to_allocate;
```

**Exceptions**:

```
struct Animal* some_function();
```

Since `some_function` is a function-identifier and not a variable-identifier, it's not really an exception.

Same for:

```
void (*some_function)(struct Animal*);
```

If there is no variable-identifier, then it belongs to the type-identifier.

**Another reason, why i stick the asterisk to the variable is**:

```
struct Animal *to_allocate, array[];
```

If the subscript operator goes with the variable-identifier, so should the asterisk.

**Note**: Once you've established your rules, stick to them. If the reader (or you) is used to or is able to recognize a pattern, that increases the readability.

**Another Note**: If i see a single asterisk, preceded and followed by space, that is for me a multiplication operator. The compiler's opinion might differ from mine, but that's how i see things.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you do int* ptr you are defining it, and when you do *ptr you are dereferencing it (reading the value on the adress it points to), if that's what you're asking

Comment: Better `int *ptr;` Why? `char* a, b, c;` certainly does not declare 3 pointers to `char`. It doesn't. It declares a single pointer and two character variables. `char *a, b, c;` makes that clear.

Comment: To dereference the pointer you need to use `*ptr`.

Comment: my bad,meant to say *ptr for dereferencing,  typo,sorry :D